# Datastax transport exception error writing

Tags: java, docker, cassandra, datastax, kundera

I have a java API application which connects to cassandra instance. My cassandra instance is hosted on google cloud platform. When I run the program in my IDE, it works fine and is able to connect to the cassandra instance. However when I deploy the application in a docker container I am getting the following error

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /104.X.X.X:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/104.X.X.X:9042] Error writing
```

From inside the container, I am able to ping the Cassandra instance. Most of the error I have seen on google end with "Connection closed" or "Channel closed" or "Cannot connect". However this one ends with "Error writing", can someone please help me troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Do you have logs from Cassandra itself?

Comment: Its not even reaching cassandra and timing out in the container. I think this might be because of the java version. I have oracle java on my machine and I have openJDK in the container, thats the only difference. I will test that out and update everyone if that works.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem. If it timeouts in container, maybe there firewalls between?

Comment: I tried with oracle jdk and it did not work. @AlexOtt all the outbound connection from docker container are open so how there be a firewall

Comment: I would recommend to perform capture of network traffic and see what happens

Comment: I have the exact same problem, I'm trying to diagnose it right now. I have a quite small range of commits that broke it so I'll probably come back with a solution soon :)

Comment: Guys, any progress in this??? 
@user3711864 did you find a solution?

Comment: I have this same problem too. I can connect from DataGrip but not from the app due to this error. My previous error is also `TransportException` but that was because I forgot to provide path to the truststore file. After I add it, still `TransportException` but I notice the "Error Writing". Does this mean it can reach cassandra but no write permission?